# Change background of button with border

Tags: android, button, background, border

I have created a button with border:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFCCCCCC" />
</shape>
```

and

```
<Button
        android:text="@null"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/colorButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border" />
```

Now I change the color of the background programmatically. The problem is that the border gets removed as soon as I change the background. Is there a way to change to background color of the button and keeping the border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
    Button colorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colorButton);
    GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) colorButton.getBackground();
    background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Gave me pretty neat direction to dig :) very well!

Answer (score 2):

Use following code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFCCCCCC" />
 <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/white"
        android:centerColor="@color/white"
        android:endColor="@color/white"/>

</shape>
```

For Changing color dynamically use following code.

```
Drawable background = yourView.getBackground();
    if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
        // cast to 'ShapeDrawable'
        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = (ShapeDrawable) background;
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToSet));
    } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
        // cast to 'GradientDrawable'
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) background;
        gradientDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToSet));
    } else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
        // alpha value may need to be set again after this call
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) background;
        colorDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToSet));
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that in the resource file the background of the button is set with the drawable and I programmatically change that background with btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
So I have to change the color of the solid in the shape and I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view no need to create cutom drawable just add any layout Apply margin `android:layout_margin="1dp"` to your button and `android:background="#FF4081"` for RelativeLayout.Now just change the **background** of your buttton.

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF4081"> 
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/colorButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@null" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's also a very neat way. I really should have thought of that earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To apply new color on same drawable use [DrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) class.

```
DrawableCompat.setTintList(d,drawableTintColor); // d is drawable object and drawableTintColor is color you want to apply
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try and get a reference to the background drawable and then apply some color, like the code I post below :

```
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) colorButton.getBackground();
    gradientDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
```

where `#FF0000` is the new color you want to display.
That way I think borders will not get removed .

Comment: it removes border